# How does CombineLatest reactive operator work?

Tags: system.reactive

I have run the following code snippet inside Linqpad:

```
$"[{(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))}] 0 0".Dump();
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .CombineLatest(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)), (x, y) => $"[{(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))}] {x} {y}")
    .Do(Console.WriteLine).Wait();
```

Here is what I've got in result:

```
[23:38:40.111] 0 0
[23:38:50.183] 2 0
[23:38:52.180] 3 0
[23:38:55.196] 4 0
[23:38:58.197] 5 0
[23:39:00.181] 5 1
[23:39:01.198] 6 1
[23:39:04.198] 7 1
[23:39:07.210] 8 1
[23:39:10.196] 8 2
[23:39:10.211] 9 2
[23:39:13.211] 10 2
[23:39:16.211] 11 2
[23:39:19.212] 12 2
[23:39:20.197] 12 3
[23:39:22.227] 13 3
[23:39:25.228] 14 3
[23:39:28.229] 15 3
[23:39:30.196] 15 4
[23:39:31.241] 16 4
[23:39:34.242] 17 4
```

I am unable to explain the beginning of this sequence:

1. Why is the first computed value `2 0`?
2. Why `2 0` was output 10 seconds after the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

### CombineLatest

when an item is emitted by either of two Observables, combine the latest item emitted by each Observable via a specified function and emit items based on the results of this function

Maybe this modified code will help you understand what's happening:

```
$"[{(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))}] 0 0".Dump();
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
        .Do(x => $"[{(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))}] {x} _".Dump())
    .CombineLatest(
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            .Do(y => $"[{(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))}] _ {y}".Dump()),
        (x, y) => $"[{(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))}] {x} {y}")
    .Do(s => s.Dump())
    .Wait();
```

Comment: Now I understand it. The key word is **each**.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is emitted from a CombineLatest until there's at least one message from each side. That happens 10 seconds after the start in your case, when you get the first message from the 10-second observable: Three messages from the 3-second observable have come out, so the third one is emitted, paired with the first message of the 10-second one.

Comment: The emphasize is **on each side**. Now I get it.